# My template isn't loading, but base.html is?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to render a class based view through my template, `chart.html`, however I'm only able to get `{% extends 'base.html' %}` able to load when I test my app on localhost.

Below is my view and template files for my `chart.html` and `base.html`. Note that im not getting any syntax errors in my console. Would greatly appreciate some expertise here. I don't think its a URL issue because when I land on the URL, i get the base.html template loaded, just not its main template aka `chart.html`.

`views.py`

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import View

User = get_user_model()
# Create your views here.

class IndexView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, 'chart.html', {})


class ChartData(APIView):

    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        data = {
                    "sales": 100,
                    "customers": 10,
                    "users": User.objects.all().count(),
                }
        return Response(data)
```

`chart.html`

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.css'></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
{% block jquery %}
var endpoint = '/api/chartdata/'

$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: endpoint,
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data)
        console.log(data.customers)
    },
    error: function(error_data){
        console.log("error")
        console.log(error_data)
    }
})

{% endblock %}
</script> 

{% block content %}
<h1>Hello World</h1>



        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
</div>

{% endblock  %}
```

`base.html`

```
{% load static %}



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>


  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  




  
  <!-- FontAwesome -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c7b9905714.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'logos/favicon.ico' type='image/x-icon' %}">


</head>


<body>
  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light static-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div>
      <a href="{% url 'index' %}"><img src="{% static 'logos/sb.svg' %}" class="img-responsive" width="100" height="100"></a>
      <span class="badge badge-secondary">BETA</span>
      </div>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li id="link-blog"class="nav-item"> 
          <a class="nav-link" class="nav-link" href="{% url 'mybucket' %}">My Bucket</a> 
          </li>
          <li id="link-about" class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a>
          </li>
            <li id="link-home" class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'index' %}">Home
            <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- Page Content -->
{% block page_content %}{% endblock %}
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      {% block jquery %}{% endblock %}
    })
    </script>
</body>
<footer class="page-footer font-small white pt-4 bg-light">
    


<div>&nbsp;</div> 
<div>&nbsp;</div> 
<div>&nbsp;</div> 
<!-- Footer -->

  <!-- Footer Links -->
  <div class="container-fluid text-center text-md-left">

    <!-- Grid row -->
    <div class="row bg-hero text-center" style="justify-content: center;">

      <!-- Grid column -->
      
      <div class="col-md-6 mt-md-3 mt-3">
            <h5 class="text-uppercase">Follow US:</h5>
            <p class="form-text" style="color:#F58EA6;">Know when new features & updates come out!</p>

            
        
        </div>
      <!-- Grid column -->

      <hr class="clearfix w-75 d-md-none pb-3" style="width:90%;">

      <!-- Grid column -->

      <!-- Grid column -->
      <div class="col-md-6 mt-md-3 mt-3" >

        <!-- Links -->
        <h5 class="text-uppercase">Contact Info</h5>

      

      </div>
      <!-- Grid column -->

    </div>
    <!-- Grid row -->

  </div>


</footer>
<!-- Footer -->

  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
  <script src="{% static 'vendor/jquery/jquery.slim.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">$('a[href="' + this.location.pathname + '"]').parents('li,ul').addClass('active');
</script>




</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** in your base.html, you have

```
{% block page_content %}{% endblock %}
```

while in your chart.html, you have

```
{% block content %}
```

2. Even after you fixed this, your chart.html's static might not work properly.

In your chart.html, you should use something like:

```
{% extends 'base.html'%}


{% block extrahead %} 
{{ block.super }} // this one might not be necessary in your case.
{% load static %}

// your chart html specific static files.

{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

// your chart main body

{% endblock %}
```

Accordingly, in your base.html,

```
<head>
// your other head components

{% block extrahead %} 
{% endblock %}
 </head>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me solve the issue, I changed my chart.html to block page_content instead. Is there anything wrong with just removing the `page` part from base and chart? Just asking for curiosity.

Comment: you just need to keep the same. also I feel your static files might not be served well. Please see my updated answer. If your static files serving well, do not bother change things, but the above answer about static files is a good practice.

Comment: Thank you for the extra safe guarding! I actually didn't have any problem loading static but I will keep this piece of code close to me incase I encounter any problems!